# Как наследоваться от класса Twitter в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, twitter, twitter-api

Пытаюсь расширить класс `yii\authclient\clients\Twitter`, чтобы вытягивать при логине пользователя через Твиттер его `$oauth_token` и `$oauth_verifier`, и сохранять их в базу.

Создал ребёнка:

```
namespace path\to\my\TwitterChild;

class Twitter extends yii\authclient\clients\Twitter
{
    protected function saveAccessToken(OAuthToken $token){

        file_put_contents('path/to/tmp/1',"Got it!");

        return parent::saveAccessToken($token);


    }
}
```

Дописал в `common/config/main.php` в секции `components`

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class'   => \yii\authclient\Collection::className(),
    'clients' => [
        'twitter' => [
           'class'          => 'path\to\my\TwitterChild',
           'consumerKey'    => 'InZnNj4lkfdv784Fdq',
           'consumerSecret' => 'ziWfRtsdv8999fdvdfklb8vhyc3',
         ],
    ],
],
```

Результат нулевой. Отсюда вопрос: как правильно реализовать переопределение класса Twitter?

Comment: А что значит результат нулевой? Может быть поподробнее? Метод ничего не возвращает или к самому классу нельзя обратиться или ошибки какие-то выдает и прочее.

Answer (score 1):

Решено. Класс не подхватывался из-за наличия того же элемента (`authClientCollection -> Twitter`) в массиве в файле `main-local.php`.